# QueryDSL add this path as source to the query exception

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

Environment: Spring, JPA, Hibernate

I am getting this Stacktrace (class names modified):

```
Undeclared path 'fooPK'. Add this path as a source to the query to be able to reference it.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Undeclared path 'fooPK'. Add this path as a source to the query to be able to reference it.
org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:293)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:106)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.findOne(Unknown Source)
com.adc.common.config.service.XServiceImpl.getByConfigName(XServiceImpl.java:49)
```

I am trying to do this:

```
public static final Predicate getByCodeAndName(
        final String sCode,
        final String sName) {

    BooleanExpression expression = null;
    QFooPK fooPK = QFooPK.fooPK;
    QFoo foo = QFoo.foo;

    expression = fooPK.code.eq(sCode)
            .and(foo.name.eq(sName));

    return expression;
}
```

QFooPK is a object defined as a PK of QFoo,
and the relationships have been automatically defined by QueryDSQL via Maven.

I'm trying to do achieve a query like this:

> SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE XCODE = 'code' AND XNAME = 'name'

TABLE1.XCODE and TABLE1.YCODE would be the composite primary keys and TABLE1.XNAME just a field.

I'm not sure what's causing the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QFooPK.fooPK` is a top level variable and not related to your entity. Your example should work like this

```
public static final Predicate getByCodeAndName(
    final String sCode,
    final String sName) {
    QFoo foo = QFooVal.foo;
    return foo.id.code.eq(sCode)
        .and(foo.name.eq(sName));
}
```

Replace `id` with your id property name.

Comment: I was originally doing it as foo.id().fooPK.code(sCode). No wonder it wasn't working.